# Generating drawables from SVG for Android with gradle on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, svg, gradle, android-drawable

Situation: 
I got SVG files from a Designer.

Icon Fonts are not easy to use in standard Android components.

So i need drawables for all my supported sizes

Everything should be automated through Gradle.

Used:

I found and used this nice plugin 
https://github.com/eowise/gradle-imagemagick

Unfortunately it doesn't worked out of the box.
I allways got "No such file or directory" from gradle.
It is unable to find the ImageMagick convert tool which is used by the plugin.

Straight from the shell without gradle the generated call for convert is working.

Comment: https://github.com/trello/victor

Comment: nice, i will check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i fixed it for me and i will write it down to give a short cut for this.

Installation:
execute from the shell

- brew update
- brew install imageMagick
- brew install librsvg

Setup:

Setting the PATH variable doesn't worked for me. I had to write the installation path of the imageMagick convert tool to /etc/launchd.conf
I found the info here: [https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x][1]

again shell:

- sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf
- sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf

add this line:

- setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

You can check where convert is installed. Type "which convert" in a shell. For now it was /usr/local/bin

After saving modified laundchd.conf.

RESTART

Configuration of Gradle:

Add the following snippet to you global build.gradle script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.eowise:gradle-imagemagick:0.4.0'
    }
}

task svgToPNG {
[
        [ variant: 'mdpi', size: '32x32' ],
        [ variant: 'hdpi', size: '48x48' ],
        [ variant: 'xhdpi', size: '64x64' ],
        [ variant: 'xxhdpi', size: '96x96' ],
        [ variant: 'xxxhdpi', size: '128x128']
].each {
    item ->
        task( "buildIcons${item.variant.capitalize()}", type: com.eowise.imagemagick.tasks.Magick) {
            convert './app/src/main/svgResources', { include '*.svg' }
            into "./app/src/main/res/drawable-${item.variant}"
            actions {
                -background('none')
                inputFile()
                -resize(item.size)
                outputFile { filename, extension -> "${filename}.png" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adjust the paths to you SVG resources and your app Module.

Now you can run 
- ./gradlew svgToPNG

and you will get for each drawable category a single task.

- buildIconsHdpi buildIconsMdpi buildIconsXhdpi buildIconsXxhdpi buildIconsXxxhdpi

Run them all and you should see your newly generated assets under the given drawable folders

Happy Generating!